# OpenVPN bridging vs routing: which is more secure?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have read about the [differences between routing and bridging in OpenVPN](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting), but I haven't found much from a security perspective. Which of the two modes is more secure?

Comment: It's not an issue of security, but of features: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#vpntype

Comment: @schroeder the page you linked also states the following though: "Routing also provides a greater ability to selectively control access rights on a client-specific basis."

Comment: Sure, but that's a feature. Selective control of access does not make one more 'secure' than another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non is more secure, they are both equally secure, and many routing features provide VPN's, so it really does depend on features, but in terms of security, they are the same.